# Viewing Graph from saved .pbtxt file on Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I just have a **graph.pbtxt** file. I want to view the graph in **tensorboard**. But I am not aware of how to do that. Do I have to write any python script or can I do it from the terminal itself? Kindly help me to know the steps involved.

Comment: I think you will need a .pb file for that. You can load it using the `tf.train.Saver()`. You will load it in a `tf.Session`. From there you can call `tf.summary.FileWriter( session.graph , '/temp' )`. This method will return a `FileWriter` object. You can call the `filewriter.write()` method. This will create a .event file in the /temp directory. Then, in your terminal : `tensorboard --logdir=/temp`

Comment: I believe I can follow the mentioned steps only if I have the source code but I dont have the source code actually. I just have this .pbtxt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save `.pb` file from your `.pbtxt` with `tf.train.write_graph`

```
from google.protobuf import text_format

with open('graph.pbtxt') as f:
    text_graph = f.read()
graph_def = text_format.Parse(text_graph, tf.GraphDef())
tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, path, 'graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

Then you can load it in `tf.Session`. Take a look at this gist
https://gist.github.com/jubjamie/2eec49ca1e4f58c5310d72918d991ef6

Comment: how can you visualize it on Tensorboard after obtaining the `graph.pb` file?

Answer (score 5):

Open tensorboard and use the "Upload" button on the left to upload the pbtxt file will directly open the graph in tensorboard.